# Converge or Diverge: Alternating

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

Does this $\sum_{n=2020}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n (\ln(n))^{137}}{n^{1.01}}$ absolutely converge, conditionally converge, or diverge?

When I try in Wolfram Alpha with absolute value, it works... but it doesn't pass alternating series test for decreasing...

Comment: Why do you think the alternating series test doesn't work here?

Comment: The positive part of the summand IS decreasing for all $n>N$ for some number $N$.